# How to prove that $\sum_1^{\infty} \frac{nx^2}{n^3 + x^3}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

my goal here is:

> To prove that \begin{align}f(x) =  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{nx^2}{n^3 + x^3} \end{align} converge pointwise on $[0, \infty)$.

Because what I really want is to prove that $\forall A> 0$,the serie on the interval $[0,A]$ converge uniformly (if serie converge pointwise then converge uniformly on a compact interval).

1. **So this is the best way to do that?**
2. **How can I prove that series converges pointwise on $[0, \infty)$?**

I have trying to do this too:

> \begin{align} f'(x) = \sum \frac{n(2n^3 - x^4)}{(n^3 + x^3)^2} \leq \sum\frac{n^4}{n^6} = \sum \frac{1}{n^2} \end{align}

And this last series is convergent, so I can conclude that the derivative of f is bounded, then f is Lipschitz. But this let me conclude what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x\ge 0$ then the summand is bounded by $\frac {x^2}{n^2}$, if $x\le A$, use the [Weierstrass M test](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeierstrassM-Test.html)  with majorants $A^2/n^2$ to show uniform convergence on $[0,A]$.

Comment: So because of  the summand is bounded by $\frac{x^2}{n^2}$ and this go to zero is suffice to prove pointwise convergence  on $[0, \infty)$

Comment: The summand going to 0 is not sufficient for convergence of the series in general. However, in this case, the summand is bounded by $x^2/n^2$ so the series is bounded by $x^2\sum n^{-2}=(\pi x)^2/6$ and thus converges pointwise for every $x\ge 0$.

Answer (score 2):

On the interval $[0, A]$ observe that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^K\frac{nx^2}{n^3+x^3}\leq \sum_{n=1}^K\frac{nx^2}{n^3}\leq \sum_{n=1}^K\frac{A^2}{n^2}
$$
from which the uniform convergence is obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Another (overly complicated in this case) proof would be using that $\int_1^\infty {\rm d}n \frac{n x^2}{n^3+x^3}$ is finite for $x\ge 0$ which implies that $\sum_{n=1}^n \frac{n x^2}{n^3+x^3}$ is finite for $x\ge 0$ as well. To show that the integral is finite, calculate partial fractions first:
$$ \frac{n x^2}{n^3+x^3} = \frac{2 n x - n^2}{3 (n^2 - n x + x^2)} + \frac{n}{3 (n + x)}. $$
Integrating this over n from $1$ to $\infty$ yields the finite result for $x\ge 0$:
$$\frac{1}{6}x \left( 2\,\ln  \left( x+1 \right) -\ln  \left( -x+{x}^{2}+1
 \right) +2\,\sqrt {3}\arctan \left( {\frac {x-2}{\sqrt{3} x}} \right) +\pi \,\sqrt {3} \right).$$